# Can't see apps in admin site

Tags: django, django-admin

I am a complete django newbie and I'm making my first app and I'm stuck in the admin. For some reason, my models/apps are not showing in the admin panel.

In the admin panel I get the following error

**You don't have permission to edit anything.**

I am logged in as super user. I confirmed this.

project structure:

```
deals_site_main

    deals
        __pycache__
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py

    deals_site_main
        __pycache__
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        wsgi.py

    manage.py
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from deals.models import Item,Deal


class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=['name','description']

admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
admin.site.register(Deal)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.    

class Item(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=125)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    price=models.FloatField()


class Deal(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=125)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    minimum_quantity=models.IntegerField()
    price=models.FloatField()
    item=models.ForeignKey(Item)
```

settings.py

```
# Django settings for deals_site_main project.

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'tbf_deals',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',
        'HOST': 'localhost',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '5432',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}

# Hosts/domain names that are valid for this site; required if DEBUG is False
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# In a Windows environment this must be set to your system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/var/www/example.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = 'odr@r^9hp9ur)%fnqm(u%yy%+02j2wpx5z2=95d+4_xdu&%%2u'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'deals_site_main.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'deals_site_main.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
     'django.contrib.admindocs',
     'deals',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'deals_site_main.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^deals_site_main/', include('deals_site_main.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: uncomment the two lines in your urls.py below the text that says uncomment to enable admin... autodiscover() is required.

Comment: oops.. thanks. post as anwer and i will accept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uncomment the two lines in your urls.py below the text that says uncomment to enable admin... [autodiscover() is required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf).

```
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
```

Comment: I never had the `admin.autodiscover` in my urlconfig, as the docs say: "Typically you won’t need to call this function directly as AdminConfig calls it when Django starts." - But after a release, the django admin spontaneously stopped working (throwing this error when trying to access /admin: `Reverse for 'app_list' not found.`) Adding autodiscover to the urlconfig solved this problem, even though I'm still not sure why..

Answer (score 3):

Uncomment these two lines in your `urls.py` file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
```